# How do I avoid the "too many connections" error message is shown?

Tags: 7, theming

How do I avoid the following error message is shown to normal users?

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections in lock_may_be_available()

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. Users are seeing site error messages that they shouldn't
2. The error message itself

For 1, go to `admin/config/development/logging` and set **Error messages to display** to None.  Don't worry, this won't affect messages like "incorrect login details" or "page not found, we did a search instead" ... things that the user really needs to know.

As for 2, here are a couple of things to try:

- Turn off all your custom modules if you have any, re-enable them one by one to see if you can find the cause
- Do the same with contributed modules
- [Read up on the error message](https://www.google.com.au/webhp#q=pdoexception+sqlstate+1040), there are too many things that could be causing it that are non-drupal specific to be useful on this site.

Comment: Actually `Error messages to display` is already set to None.